# How to do Activiti workflow integration with JSF application

Tags: jsf, jpa, workflow, activiti

I am new to Activiti workflow. I just wanted to implement a JSF application with activiti workflow with out maven dependency. I am using JPA for databases connectivity. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*activiti-cdi* might be the keyword you are looking for. It makes the integration with (among others) JSF pretty easy, see for example this tutorial: http://www.bpm-guide.de/2011/09/17/build-your-own-activiti-task-explorer-with-cdi-and-jsf-2/

Answer (score 1):

There are different tools to implement workflows in JSF.

Is simple: http://www.imixs.org/jee/examples/jsf_example.html

I recommend the most is "Spring Web Flow" - Simple example: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-web-flow-webapp.html

Regards,