# JSF2 Activiti bmpn 5.10 web application example for glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3, activiti

Could some one point to a simple application using JSF2 and Activiti BPMN integration workflow on glassfish 3.1.2, Activiti 5.10 ? I tried the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173533/how-to-do-activiti-workflow-integration-with-jsf-application) however I am reciving weld exception as shown below:

```
    org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [TaskService] 
    with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private
    com.camunda.fox.demo.twitter.jsf.TaskList.taskService]   
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:311)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:280)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:143)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:163)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:382)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:367)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:380)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:199)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

How to resolve this error on Glassfish 3.1.2?

I tried to copy the latest weld 2.1 snapshot to glassfish lib folder however it did not work. I also tried an example that came with Activiti in action source code.

Any clues on how to resolve this error or a sample application whih would work on Glassfish will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weld errors got resolved by including all the activiti related jars in the project.